# How to catch "= already refers to: #'clojure.core/= in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/= " in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In my app I'm providing some interface to users that they can provide code and app evaluates that code within sandbox(so `eval` fn not allowed).The thing is I need to catch if user overrides some built-in function such as `=`

Any ideas how to catch and prevent that thing?(The idea is they should not be able to do that)

Code:

```
(defn =
  []
  //some code)

WARNING: = already refers to: #'clojure.core/= in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/=
```

**One solution might be:**

I was trying to get the warning message as `String` but `with-out-str` function did not work.

```
(with-out-str
 (defn = [])) 
;=> ""
```

Also wrote that `with-err-str`(changed **with-out-str** little bit) did not work as well.

```
(defmacro with-err-str
  [& body]
  `(let [s# (new java.io.StringWriter)]
     (binding [*err* s#]
       ~@body
       (str s#))))

(with-err-str
 (defn = [])) 
;=> ""
```

Need: `"WARNING: = already refers to: #'clojure.core/= in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/="`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work when you use `eval`:

```
user=> (with-err-str (eval '(defn - [] 11)))
"WARNING: - already refers to: #'clojure.core/- in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/-\n"
user=> (re-seq #"WARNING" (with-err-str (eval '(defn / [] 11))))
("WARNING")
```

Or you could redefine the `defn` macro in user's code, but nothing prevents them to use other clojure tools to redefine a var:

```
user=> (defmacro defn-safe
  #_=>   [nam & decls]
  #_=>   (if (resolve (symbol "clojure.core" (name nam)))
  #_=>     (print "Whoops")
  #_=>     (list* `defn (with-meta nam (assoc (meta nam) :private true)) decls)))
#'user/defn-safe
user=> (defn-safe foo [x] (+ x 2))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 22)
24
user=> (defn-safe = [a b] (- a b))
Whoopsnil
user=>
```

Another option, and probably your best bet is using
https://github.com/clojure/tools.analyzer

Comment: > they can provide code and app evaluates that code
how do you do it then? (edit the question plz)

Comment: yeah you are right but there are some internal things that I did not say which I needed to say I guess, since it's running in sandbox eval fn is not allowed :/ but I really liked your answer gonna try to make it work for my use case

Answer (score 2):

[clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail) handles this (and many other things as well). If you're looking to sandbox Clojure, I'd recommend taking a look.

Comment: I'm using clojail already, yep also worked! (let [writer (java.io.StringWriter.)] 
  (sb '(println "blah") {#'*err* writer}) (str writer)) ; Returns "blah\n"

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be like this:

```
(def before (set (vals (ns-map *ns*))))

(defn = [])

(def after (set (vals (ns-map *ns*))))

(clojure.set/difference before after)

;=> #{#'clojure.core/=}
```